What is the best approach for class inheritance and custom view tracking in Django?
I'm trying to figure out how to properly use class inheritance in Django. One thing I'm struggling with is making a custom view that keeps track of what users are doing. The main thing I'm stuck on is the class I made:
class Tracker:
    activity = None

    def action(self, *login_user: User, whom: User, is_current: bool) -> None:
        """Create Action model"""
        ...


    def visitor(self, login_user: User, whom: User) -> None:
        """create a Visitor model"""
        ...

    @validate_view_inheritance
    def tracker(self, login_user: User, whom: User):
        url_user = self.kwargs.get("username")
        login_user: User = self.request.user
        is_current_user = login_user.username == url_user
        self.action(login_user=login_user, whom=whom, is_current=is_current_user)
        self.visitor(whom, login_user)


You can noticed  that I'm trying to get info about request and kward, but they're not part of the class itself. It seems to work only when I inherit this class with certain Views. Is this the right way to do it? Additionally, I use a custom decorator that checks if this class is a subclass of View. If not, it raises an ImproperlyConfigured error.
In the future, I want to use this class to make custom views like this:
class CustomDetailView(DetailView, EpulsTracker):
    activity = ActionType.PROFILE

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Overrides the get method."""
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)

        # Track user action
        self.tracker()

        return self.render_to_response(context)

I plan to add similar tracking to other views like ListView and DeleteView ..., where I'll use self.tracker() in the get method. This way, I can easily use it in my project:
class ExampleView(LoginRequiredMixin, CustomDetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = "sample.html"
    activity = ActionType.PROFILE

What do you think? Is inheriting classes like this a good way to do it, or is there a better approach?
